# How to display model in QML with pages?

Tags: qt, view, model, qml

I have problem with displaying model with pages, and I can't find what is proper way to do this.

I have `ListView` which has model of 15 rectangles like in the picture below.[image]

There is property `currentPage` which is changed when clicking the buttons. I want to be able to display:

*0-4 elements in the first page*
*5-9 in the second*
*And last 5 on the third page.*

I know that I can create them for example `FirstPage.qml`, `SecondPage.qml`... And use them directly, but I want to display Items from model. The `ListView` is not important it can be any component but I want to use model.

What is the best way to achieve this? Any idea suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Maybe `positionViewAtIndex` would be helpful?

Comment: @JarMan thank you so much that is one solution. I added to my list `interactive: false` and followed your suggestion. The only left is to find solution if there are ex. 11 or 12 elements to make space in the list view end so the 10th element appear on the top of the list but I will find way for this and post update.  Please add your suggestion as answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: looks like it cant be removed :) from documentation: `If positioning the view at index would cause empty space to be displayed at the beginning or end of the view, the view will be positioned at the boundary.`

Comment: But works if you decrease the height of the listView in the last page and set it back to original height in other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView has a method called `positionViewAtIndex()` that will allow you to specify which item to scroll to. So for your case, you could do something like this:

```
Button {
    id: previousBtn
    onClicked: {
        listView.positionViewAtIndex(listView.currentIndex - 5);
    }
}
Button {
    id: nextBtn
    onClicked: {
        listView.positionViewAtIndex(listView.currentIndex + 5);
    }
}
```